# MySQL different conditions from same column

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I'm using a reporting tool for Mac OSX clients called MunkiReport. This tool uses a MySQL database with a table called `inventoryitem` that looks like this (I left some columns out):

```
|     id    | serial_number | path
|     1     |     C01       | Applications/Application01.app
|     2     |     C01       | Applications/Application02.app
|     3     |     C01       | Applications/Application03.app
|     4     |     C02       | Applications/Application01.app
|     5     |     C02       | Applications/Application03.app
|     6     |     C02       | Applications/Application04.app
```

Now let's say I want to list all serial_numbers that have both Application01 and Application03 installed, I do it like this:

```
SELECT `serial_number`
FROM `inventoryitem`
WHERE `path` IN ('Applications/Application01.app','Applications/Application03.app')
GROUP BY `serial_number`
HAVING COUNT(`path`)=2
```

Output would be:

```
| serial_number |
|     C01       |
|     C02       |
```

But, what I actually want is to list all serial_numbers that DO have Application03 installed but DON'T have Application02 installed...

I've tried several things but I can't get it right. I thought maybe a subquery? First list the Application03 and from that data list all serial_numbers without Application02.

I'm a bit of a rookie with MySQL so it puzzles me a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try aggregating conditional expressions in the HAVING clause - like so:

```
SELECT `serial_number`
FROM `inventoryitem`
WHERE `path` IN ('Applications/Application02.app','Applications/Application03.app')
GROUP BY `serial_number`
HAVING COUNT(case `path` when 'Applications/Application03.app' then 1 end)=1
   AND COUNT(case `path` when 'Applications/Application02.app' then 1 end)=0
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it. MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). It should output four serial_numbers. Shadow's solution seems to work.

Comment: @Matter: That's because I should have either used `COUNT` instead of `SUM`, or included an `else 0` clause in the `CASE` expression. I've amended it so that it should work, now.

Comment: Yes, this also works great. And it's quite simple to add more applications to it!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get the desired output using subquery. I would use a [NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) subquery to achive the desired output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `serial_number`
FROM `inventoryitem` i1
WHERE `path`='Applications/Application03.app'
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `inventoryitem` i2 WHERE i2.`path`='Applications/Application02.app' and i2.serial_number=i1.serial_number)
```

But you can do it with an IN() operator or with a left join as well. But I will leave those example for others or for yourself to figure out.

Comment: Thanks, this works! One more question. This query outputs the serial_number. I would like to have the computer_name. This information is in another table called `machine`. I know how to perform a simple JOIN: `SELECT computer_name
FROM machine
INNER JOIN inventoryitem
ON inventoryitem.serial_number=machine.serial_number`

Comment: Just add the where criteria from the answer to your query (pay attention to the table aliases though).

Answer (score 0):

JOIN a SELECT statement that grabs all the serial numbers with application 3 installed with a SELECT statement that lists all the serial numbers without application 2 installed (JOIN ON serial_number)